# Почему не видно классов библиотеки?

Tags: android, github, библиотеки, gradle, jar

Опубликовал библиотеку на bintray.com и jCenter, пользуясь этой инструкцией:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/266801

Все успешно загрузилось и опубликовалось, однако при подключении библиотеки классов библиотеки не видно (Gradle синхронизируется без ошибок). Вот сама библиотека:

https://github.com/ImangazalievM/FadingButton

А вот строка подключения библиотеки:

```
compile 'com.github.imangazalievm:fadingbutton:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Да всё вроде видно. Только я бы рекомендовал исключить из библиотеки `BuildConfig`. Хотя использовать либу это в любом случае не мешает.

Comment: Да, действительно. Проверил на другом проекте - все работает. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @xkor опубликуйте ваш комменьарий как ответ, может многим поможет

Comment: @Saidolim как то не представляю чем мой ответ может ещё кому то помочь. Это скорее опровержение вопроса чем ответ на него...